# Store multiple user to one activity - which technique?

Tags: swift

I would like to store multiple user to one activity like:

```
Play Nintendo
-> Rick
-> Peter
-> John
```

The case now is, that I can have also multiple activities like:

```
Play Nintendo
-> Rick
-> Peter
-> John

Swim
-> John
-> Robert
```

My goal is to have all this activities and the depending user in one (Multidimensional?) array, which I could save permanent in the device memory.

Also the device-user should be able to add user at any point to any activity.

Can you give me a hint, how I should handle this? Im stuck in space and would appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `NSUserDefaults` and an `NSObject`-class to save the data.

(I can't test code, because the lack of Xcode :-) )

```
class Activity:NSObject {
    var activity:String!
    var users:[String]

    init(activity:String, users:[String]){
        self.activity = activity
        self.users = users
    }
}


class test:UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        var user = Activity(activity: "Play Nintendo", users: ["Ryan", "bill"])
        var activity = loadActivity("Play Nintendo")
    }

    //Load existing activity for a name
    func loadActivity(activityName:String)->Activity{

        if(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(activityName) != nil){
            let theActivity:Activity = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(activityName) as Activity
            return theActivity
        }else{
            var newActivity = Activity(activity: activityName, users: [])
            saveNewActivity(newActivity)
            return newActivity
        }
    }

    func saveNewActivity(activity:Activity){
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(activity, forKey: activity.activity)
    }

    func addUserForActivity(activity:String, user:String){
        //Loads the activity with the users by using the activity as key
        var theActivities:Activity = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(activity) as Activity

        //append a new user to the activity
        theActivities.users.append(user)

        //save the activities in the userdefaults
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(theActivities, forKey: activity)
    }
}
```